# Data binding ktx is not enabled

Tags: android, android-databinding, gradle-kotlin-dsl

So I am trying to handle `StateFlow` inside the `xml` file to enable/disable the button:

```xml
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/login_button_login"
                    style="@style/EspritButton.Dark"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/settings_item_button_height"
                    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                    android:text="@string/login_button_title"
                    android:enabled="@{viewModel.enableButton}"/>
```

But when I try to build the project, I receive an error:

```
Data binding ktx is not enabled.

Add dataBinding.addKtx = true to your build.gradle to enable it.
Open File
```

I have tried setting `databinding` inside the module's `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
}

android {
    viewBinding {
        isEnabled = true
    }

    dataBinding {
        isEnabled = true
        addKtx = true
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
        dataBinding {
            addKtx = true
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel's `stateFlow` that is used here:

```
class MyViewModel(): ViewModel() {
    //...

    private val _enableButton = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val enableButton: StateFlow<Boolean> = _enableButton

    //...
}
```

Of course I have set `<layout>` tags and created `viewModel` variable in `xml`. I was searching for this for some time, but it seems there is not much results on the Internet regarding this particular error.

Btw, I have gradle plugin 7.0.0 (tried 7.1.2 with no effect), Gradle 7.0.2 and Kotlin 1.6.10.

Comment: Did you add this line in your gradle file(app level) ?
```
plugins { id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have this (I have edited the question to add plugins I have declared)